# TypeScript index type signatures

Tags: typescript

I'm quite new to TypeScript and I need to declare a type like:

```
type U = { [key: string]: number }; // any string for the keys
type T = { [key: string]: U };      // any string for the keys too
```

Example of use:

```
const test: T = {
    'aaa': {
        'xxx': 777,
        'yyy': 888,
        'zzz': 999  // error expected
    },
    'bbb': {
        'xxx': 444,
        'yyy': 555,
        'ooo': 666  // error expected
    }
};
```

Is there a way, a better and probably more complex signature, to ensure that all U properties in T will have the same keys?

Comment: are you saying you want only xxx, yyy and zzz or those 3 plus whatever else?

Comment: I don't understand the use case.  Is `ooo` a typo and you want to see an error there?  Is it intended but you want to see an error that `zzz` is missing?  Are the particular keys `xxx`, `yyy` and `zzz` important or do you want the type to enforce that *whatever* the keys are of the nested properties they are the same across each property?  Etc etc etc.  I'm hoping you can write out some more examples of what things should and should not be allowed.  Depending on how complex it is, your requirements might not be expressible as a specific type and you will instead need a generic constraint.

Comment: Sorry like you said I would like "to enforce that whatever the keys, they are the same across each property".

Comment: I think that's only going to work as a generic constraint like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA0hEBnAPAFQHxQLxSZQQAewEAdgCapQCGFIUA-FANYoD2AZoVAFxQKEAG4QATgG4AUKEhQAcp2ABlAK7iIWXAQDeUANqIoASwrsuvTAF1BAJQgBjTuKrp4SFBkwGOIHoTW2AA0QmoAtgBGErgAvjLOFKjA9KhKqhrQBFjEZJQ0isrqmtrYABQkgpgAlPi4JAmcSSnkyfip6cUQZbrSUFAA5HTDA4L6APTjxOLiLqEUnFCcy339gyQbo1AA7LvBq-0DIMdbABzn+2uDAF63WwCcj6uxl4OR71sTUxKz4vOLt2uB3Wm0EABYIa9DscQFsAKwIqGDZacLYANgx-We0li1WkQA). Does that work for you?

Comment: @jcalz I don't really like the need to use a function, but that's brilliant!!! That was the idea :)

Comment: So would you like me to write that up as an answer?  I don't think there's any way to do this without some sort of generic constraint and helper function (without the helper function you'd end up needing to annotate the type and write `xxx`, `yyy`, and `zzz` a second time).

Answer (score 1):

you can define an interface requiring some keys with an index signature:

```
interface U { 
  [key: string]: number;
  xxx: number;
  yyy: number;
  zzz: number; 
};
```

if you just want two objects to be required to have the SAME keys, you could do something with generics

```
interface BaseType<T> {
  xxx: T;
  yyy: T;
  zzz: T; 
}

type U = BaseType<number>;
type T = BaseType<U>;
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, my English is not really good, xxx, yyy & zzz are just examples, they can be any string, I just need to ensure that they will be the same in each.

Comment: so you want type U and T to be constrained to have the same keys?

Comment: No I need every U property in T to have the same property keys.

Comment: ah ok got it i think

Answer (score 1):

Define U with concrete properties you need and you will get desired behavior:

```js
type U = {
    "xxx": number,
    "yyy": number;
    "zzz": number;
}
type T = { [key: string]: U }
```

That way you get an error on `ooo`:

```js
const test: T = {
    'aaa': {
        'xxx': 777,
        'yyy': 888,
        'zzz': 999
    },
    'bbb': {
        'xxx': 444,
        'yyy': 555,
        'ooo': 666  // error expected here
    }
};
```

There is Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=30&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqlC8UDeAoK6oCIAevMC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwBo0NMRmDjyrqBuB9TALwGtSlGtwC%20KUJCgAVBMigBtANYQQhAM7BqASyIBzALqE4ElCgDGAeyJaowCFsJzEqDFADkAQx8fCb9wwPXGw-KAB2SPpAoOYQMIAOJOiYzwE%20MIBObJ4oMRT0DwpisICY4NwwgBYagsCPOLCAVha69w8rTrCANl70AHp%20qBpqK2ph7EgLBwATKAALGghciTFOIA) with full example.